# Google sheets как использовать диапазон, получаемый формулой, в формуле VLOOKUP

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Использую формулу VLOOKUP в google sheets. Вторым параметром в этой формуле выступает диапазон. Когда в эту формулу диапазон вводится путём "прямого" указания, то всё работает. Пример:

```
=VLOOKUP(2;$A$1:$B$13;2;false)
```

если же мы укажем ту же самую формулу путём указания диапазона с помощью формулы ADDRESS в виде:

```
=VLOOKUP(2;ADDRESS(1;1)&":"&ADDRESS(13;2);2;false)
```

то формула возвращает ошибку доступа значения. Значение находится за пределами диапазона.

**В целом как в формуле VLOOKUP в качестве диапазона использовать значение получаемое формулой ADDRESS?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`АДРЕС` - текстовая функция (возвращает текст)

`ADDRESS(1;1)&":"&ADDRESS(13;2)` - не ссылка, а обычный текст. Его можно преобразовать в ссылку:

`INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;1)&":"&ADDRESS(13;2))`

Но это плохой вариант - текстовые функции медленные. `INDIRECT` - тоже текстовая, да еще и летучая (пересчитывается при любом изменении на листе) и  имеет несколько критичных ограничений. Да и создавать текстовое представление, потом преобразовывать его в ссылку...

Быстрый вариант с динамичным диапазоном:

```
=VLOOKUP(2;A1:INDEX(B:B;13);2;)
```

Летучесть этой формулы - только при открытии книги.

При необходимости начало диапазона (`A1`) тоже можно задать функцией `INDEX`